# Problem with connection from docker to app in network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, gitlab

Im learnig about docker and docker compose. I build compose for runing gitlab with external database. I run docker on VM with Ubuntu 22. I setup 2 container, gitlab and postgres. I need configure gitlab to using LDAP but i cant connect from container to host in network but the same telnet works from VM where i run this container.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'localhost'
    container_name: gitlab-ce
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG:
        external_url 'http://localhost'
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8443:443'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      gitlab:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/db/:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    networks:
      gitlab:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
networks:
  gitlab:
    name: gitlab-network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

Any advice to solve this problems?

I prepare configuration but dosent work, any advice to what i need to change or check.

Comment: What connections exactly don't work?  The container-private IP addresses are unreachable in almost all circumstances, so if you're trying to directly connect to one of the 10.5.0.x addresses I could see running into trouble.  I might simplify this setup by deleting all of the `networks:` blocks and letting Compose set up the networking for you.

Comment: @DavidMaze I run in docker gitlab. My IT team have LDAP server and i try connect my gitlab with LDAP. Telnet from VM works fine but when i try connect from container to ldap server i got timeout.

Comment: That seems like much more of a network-setup problem than a programming-related question, and possibly another site like [sf] would be a more appropriate place to ask.